# Access global javascript object defined within iframe src

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe set to a src on the same site. Inside the iframe page, I have a namespace called  Rack that contains a module called app...

```
Rack.app = function() {...}();
```

Can I access that Rack.app object from my outer page - the page that contains the iframe? I want to do something like

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('rackFrame');
iframe.contentWindow.Rack.app.doSomething();
```

But that doesn't work, I don't see the Rack object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you hack it by calling a function in the iframe outside of a namespace that calls the namespace?

> var iframe = document.getElementById('rackFrame');
>   iframe.contentWindow.rackTrigger();

Then in the iframe have a function:

> function rackTrigger() {
>   Rack.app.doSomething();
>   }

Not the most elegant solution if there's a single function you're looking to trigger, but cleaner if there are a number of changes you would want to make on the iframe.

Comment: Cheers, but for some reason my parent page can't see iframe.contentWindow.rackTrigger either (once I've added it of course)